# Using Groovy AntBuilder() with an optional JVM parameter

Tags: java, groovy, maven-plugin

I'm trying to update a maven plugin that's written in groovy to use an external JVM if it's available, otherwise, just use the default. My code changes look something like this:

```
def jvmExecutable = null;
if (someCondtion = true) {
 jvmExecutable = "something"
}

def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.java(fork: "${fork}", jvm: "${jvmExecutable}"....)
```

Is there a way in Groovy to leave off the `jvm: "${jvmExecutable}"` directive if jvmExecutable is null? The Groovy Ant task expects an executable there if `jvm` is specified, but I'd like it to use it's default if I don't specify something.

Essentially, if `jvmExecutable != null` do this

`ant.java(fork: "${fork}", jvm: "${jvmExecutable}", ....)`

or if `jvmExecutable == null` do this

`ant.java(fork: "${fork}", ....)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you pass named parameters into method you are actually building hashmap

so this code

```
ant.echo(message:"hello", level:"error")
```

equals to this one

```
ant.echo( [message:"hello", level:"error"] )
```

finally you want to keep in the map only valid values. like this:

```
ant.echo( [message:"hello", level:null].findAll{it.value!=null} )
```

Comment: So that didn't quite work... What is the significance of the `it` variable in `{it.value!=null}`?

Comment: Ah, nm I figured it out. It was the ${} variable substitution was becoming a blank string instead of null

Comment: to exclude null and empty values you can use this: `[ ... ].findAll{it.value}` . btw: `it` is the default name of the parameter of a closure. kind of `this` for the class in java. see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)